# FindOne inside save inside a for loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

Hey guys I am trying to use this code and I'm pretty sure that there's an asynchronous problem here involving MongoDB findOne and save inside a for loop.

```
   restArray.forEach(function(restArr)
    {
         var temp = new Restaurant ({
               nameOfRest: restArr.restaurant.name,
               favoriteFoods:[],
    });
                    console.log(restArr.restaurant.name);
            //Find a restaurant and if it can't find one:
           //Set up a new one. 
          Restaurant.findOne({nameOfRest: restArr.restaurant.name}).then(function(err,data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log("Error in finding.");
                    }

                    else if(!data)
                    {
                        //console.log(temp);
                        temp.save().then(function(err){
                            if(err) {
                                console.log("Error in saving");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                     //console.log(data);
                });
     });
```

I've been trying to look at documentation but still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You are correct.If you want to run these kinds of things either use forEach loop or it would be better if you can use ```async``` module of node.js

Comment: Would a forEach loop alone solve my problem or do I need both a forEach loop and the async module?

Comment: forEach will resolve your problem but we are not suppose to do that at it runs synchronously and can result in a callback hell..so i rather prefer to use ```async``` module which will make my code much cleaner and eaiser

Comment: Can you give an example of what I would do in my case please I've looked at documentation of it and am still confused about how to set it up for myself

Comment: you are running into a race condition problem.  Restaurant.findOne will respond when the first document is found, then reference temp, which will be the last item that was created.  If you want this to work within the context of your code, then create a new function that is dedicated to finding documents.  Please see the bottom of my answer below under ***** UPDATED ****

Comment: @Nuspeed1 You solved my problem thank you so much.

Comment: @MichaelGee glad i can help out.  would you mind clicking the accepted answer button below.  i'm trying to build my street cred.

Comment: @Nuspeed1 alright I clicked the checkmark hopefully that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dove into node about 8months back and have the scars of trial and error to prove it.
Hopefully I can save you some headaches by introducing you to promises.  This will make code performant, readable, avoid race conditions, and *promising*.

Here is the reformatted version of your syntax.

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Promise = require('bluebird'); // Promise library

Mongoose.Promise = Promise; // Set mongoose to use bluebird as the promise library.  Bluebird comes with a lot of useful promise utilities not found in the stock Promise library. 

let restaurants = ["kfc", "churcheschicken", "chicken and waffles"];

let promises = [];

restaurants.forEach((name, idx, arr) => {

    promises.push(Mongoose.models.Restaurant.findOne({ "nameOfRest": name })); 

})


// handle all errors
let onAllErrors = function(err){
    // do something with errors
}

let onDocumentSaved = function(newSavedDocument){ 
    // do something with saved document
}


// Run array of promises through this chain.
Promise.mapSeries(promises, (rest, idx, length) => {

        //rest will be a model found in your database

        if (!rest) { //not found, lets create a new restaurant
            let newRest = new Mongoose.models.Restaurant({
                nameOfRest: restaurants[idx],
                favoriteFoods:[],
            })
            // return items will be found in RESULTS in the next .then chain
            return newRest.save().then(onDocumentSaved).catch(onAllErrors);
        }
    })
    .then(RESULTS => {
        // returned from above
    })
    .catch(onPromiseError));
```

******* UPDATED *******

```
var findOrCreate = function(){
    console.log(restArr.restaurant.name);
    //Find a restaurant and if it can't find one:
    //Set up a new one. 
    Restaurant.findOne({nameOfRest: this.nameOfRest})
        .then(exist => {
            if (!exist) {
                this.save()
                    .then(result => {
                        console.log(result);
                        //document saved
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            debugger;
            //reject(err);
        });
}

restArray.forEach(function(restArr)
    {
         var temp = new Restaurant ({
               nameOfRest: restArr.restaurant.name,
               favoriteFoods:[],

             findOrCreate.call(temp);
    });

});
```